# WebSphere Liberty Profile: Batch container is not available

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

Trying to start a batch job from a servlet and receiving the following error:

javax.batch.operations.BatchRuntimeException: The batch container is not available.
at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator(BatchRuntime.java:63)

Have the following features enabled:

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager onError="FAIL">
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>managedBatch-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>collectiveController-1.0</feature>
    <feature>javaBatch-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Tim

Comment: What Liberty version are you running?   
For batch support you will need latest beta https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/ with extended content.

Comment: Yep, that's the one I have: wlp-beta-runtime-2014.10.0.0 and wlp-beta-extended-2014.10.0.0

Comment: I'm not an expert on batch, however this might be a bug. Try to post it in wasdev forum here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/?community=wasdev

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try. Question is re-asked at: [wasdev](http://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29889/liberty-october-beta-batch-container-is-not-available/?community=wasdev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a properly configured batch persistence interface. Nothing in the start-up sequence complained so it was difficult to debug. The details are outlined in http://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29889/liberty-october-beta-batch-container-is-not-available/?community=wasdev